# Is it possible in xcode to run an application in both the *iphone device* and *iphone simulator* at the same time?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, synchronization, ios-simulator

I want to be able to sync up the simulator with my iphone device so that if I were to do something on the simulator while it's running, it would perform the same on the device that's connected to my mac.

Is this possible? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. First of all you install project in simulator and another device whatever it is like iPad, iPod. After that you connect via bluetooth, wifi and internet connection. See this
[witap sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can do the opposite:

http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/

Perhaps you can contact them on ideas on how to do the opposite.